# Clementine says "Unauthorized" on every song i try to stream

Tags: 16.04, clementine

Today i was streaming SoundCloud to Clementine, and suddenly, Clementine tried to play all my songs but there was an error box that said "Unauthorized". Clementine just kept trying all my songs one after another, on and on and on, and I'm afraid that's going to overload my PC.

How to fix? :(

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](https://github.com/clementine-player/Clementine/issues/4332) on github, updating to a newer version of Clementine fixes this on Windows, on the same version as in the Ubuntu repository 1.2.3

```
Clementine/xenial 1.2.3+git1354-gdaddbde+dfsg-1build1 amd64
  modern music player and library organizer
```

Here is [a PPA](https://launchpad.net/~me-davidsansome/+archive/ubuntu/clementine) for the latest stable version 1.3.1

```
sudo apt purge clementine
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:me-davidsansome/clementine
sudo apt update
sudo apt install clementine
```

Comment: Ok, i'll try, but are you talking about the update where they added Rainbow Dash, and phsychadelic colors as a music visualizer?

Comment: IDK it is the latest version, others say it should fix your issue.

Comment: Well, okay. I think I'll try it.